# assigning data from http to 'this' controller

Tags: angularjs, http

I am trying to make an $http call and assign the data returned to a variable. Currently I have this code and it's working fine.

This is inside my controller:

```
.controller('sample', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    var ctrl = this;

    $http.get('somejson.json').success(function(data){
         $scope.myData = data;
    });
});
```

However, instead of assigning it to $scope, I want to assign it to my controller variable instead. But ctrl is always undefined inside my get function. Am I missing something here? I tried reading the doc from angular but no luck. Thanks!

This doesn't work:

```
.controller('sample', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        var ctrl = this;

        $http.get('somejson.json').success(function(data){
             debugger;// when I type ctrl in console, just to check, ctrl is undefined.
             ctrl.myData = data; // ctrl is undefined. is it possible to do this?
        });
    });
```

Comment: I find this very hard to believe. Are you getting an error when you try to assign a value to `ctrl.myData`? Is this your actual code? You appear to be missing a closing `]` in both of your snippets.

Comment: @JLRishe I updated my question. I actually have "debugger;" statement to debug. and when I hit my debugger, I type 'ctrl' in console just to see what value it is, and it's saying it's undefined. and good catch, but no the ] is not the problem :)

Comment: Its not possible, ctrl has function scope here. cant be seen in console. If it would have been global variable it would have been possible to get it.

Comment: @Nielarshi so it's not possible to assign to ctrl.myData?

Comment: you can do that. But u can use ctrl only within this controller function scope only. Outside this function scope this variable will not be visible or accessible

Comment: @blenzcoffee I wouldn't jump to conclusions based on the debugger. Debuggers can have scope problems sometimes. As I already asked, are you getting an error at the line `ctrl.myData = data;`? If not, then `ctrl` is not undefined.

Comment: He is trying to output it in console by typing ctrl just to check whether it has got data property or not.

Comment: @Nielarshi Some debuggers will allow the console to access the current scope where the execution is paused. But as I said, even if the debugger says something is undefined, that doesn't mean that it actually is.

Comment: If you remove var keyword it will be accessible in console, because by default javascript will give it a global scope. try just ctrl = this;

Comment: @JLRishe : actually u r right, when debugger is paused, you can access ctrl from console. I tried. New for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly in this fiddle.

```
 app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var ctrl = this;

    $http.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94145612/example.json').success(function(data
         ctrl.myData = data; // ctrl is undefined. is it possible to do this?
    });
 }]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r25akef3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working, but I can say with almost complete certainty that it is *not* because `ctrl` is undefined. Assigning `this` to another variable should work fine:

```
var ctrl = this;

$http.get('somejson.json').success(function(data){
     ctrl.myData = data;
});
```

Another option is to use `.bind()`:

```
$http.get('somejson.json').success(function(data){
    this.myData = data; // ctrl is undefined. is it possible to do this?
}.bind(this));
```

I prefer the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Note : console only make variable accessible which are defined either
>   in global or in currently executing function's scope.

First case

```
.controller('sample', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        // since it is declared as var ctrl , here it gets function scope.
        var ctrl = this;

        $http.get('somejson.json').success(function(data){
             debugger;

             // when application is paused in debugger mode, it will be accessible for that instance
             // once debugger mode is gone, console shifts current context, and doesn't make ctrl accessible


             ctrl.myData = data;
        });
    });
```

Second case

```
.controller('sample', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        // since there is no declaration as var ctrl , here it gets global scope.
        ctrl = this;

        $http.get('somejson.json').success(function(data){
             debugger;


             // ctrl will be accessible in console

             ctrl.myData = data;
        });
    });
```